# Which filter use for this effect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, filter, core-graphics, effects

I need to filter a image like this.

This is main image 
[image: Main Image]

This is the output image
[image: Output Image]

Please help me to get this effect.I am trying like this, but I am not getting the exact output.

```
-(UIImage *)setImage:(UIImage *)image_
{
    UIImage *entryImage  = image_;
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[entryImage CGImage]];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIMaskToAlpha"];
    [filter setDefaults];
    [filter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    //    CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
    CIImage *result = [filter outputImage];

    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[result extent]];

    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:[entryImage scale] orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    return newImage;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is LUT(Look Up Table) filter. You can find sample LUT filter on below link.

link : https://nghiatran.me/filter-me-color-lookup-table-part-2/

- Brad Larson's library GPUImage provide method to use LUT filter on image.

link : https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

- example link

link : [How to use GPUImageLookupFilter without GPUImageFilterGroup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965948/how-to-use-gpuimagelookupfilter-without-gpuimagefiltergroup)

Feel free to ask anything :)